# RegisterUrlRulesEvent rule to display site page

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, routes

Within a plugin I have written I would like to route POST requests to the plugin controller and GET requests to a single entity created in craft.

When the user POSTs to http://example.com/start-your-quote it should be handled by the plugin controller. When the user GETs http://example.com/start-your-quote it should load the single entity with the slug 'site-start-your-quote'

I have written the following in the hopes of achieving this:-

```php
 Event::on(
            UrlManager::class,
            UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
            static function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
                $event->rules['POST start-your-quote'] = 'craft-lp-api-helper/lpapi';
                $event->rules['GET start-your-quote'] = 'site-start-your-quote';
            }
        );
```

The POST is working as expected, however the GET results in the following error:-

> Blockquote
>   HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
>   Page not found.
>   ↵
>   Caused by: Invalid Route – yii\base\InvalidRouteException
>   Unable to resolve the request "site-start-your-quote".

Hopefully I am missing something simple and someone can point me in the righ direction?

Comment: Mmmm first thought is site-start-your-quote isn't a get request?

Comment: Thanks @joomkit but going to that slug direct in a browser works fine, it's just from the route rule I'm getting the 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have managed to achieve what I needed, I'm not sure if this is a very good way to do it though.

I've done it by getting the element of the page I needed and passing that to the route along with the template to use.

It all seems to work though.

```
Event::on(
        UrlManager::class,
        UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
        static function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
            $element = Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementByUri(
                'site-start-your-quote',
                Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite()->id,
                true);
            $event->rules['POST start-your-quote'] = 'craft-lp-api-helper/lpapi';
            $event->rules['GET start-your-quote'] = [
                'template' => '_layouts/forms/start-your-quote.twig',
                'variables' => [
                    'entry' => $element,
                ],
            ];
        }
    );
```